# Laravel 9 website Form data not saving to database and getting server error 500

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, database

I have Laravel website, then there have form for passing data to database. But while fill the form and trying to submit the data, I getting server error 500. So after I enable debug value as a 'true'. Then I saw error like this,
"Illuminate
 \ 
Database
 \ 
QueryException
PHP 8.1.15
9.17.0
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `properties` (`l_id`, `p_id`, `p_name`, `size`, `type`, `status`, `province`, `district`, `city`, `dic`, `price`, `img`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (005, 5, Thalalla - Land, 182,"

app
 / 
Http
 / 
Controllers
 / 
PropertyController
.php
 
: 50

```
$newProperty->city = $request->input('city');

$newProperty->dic = $request->input('dic');

$newProperty->price = $request->input('price');

$img = $request->file('img_path');

$path = $img->store('images/resource/property/main/', ['disk' =>   'my_files']);

$newProperty->img = "public/".$path;

    foreach ($salse as $table_data){

        if($name == $table_data->p_name && $district == $table_data->district){

            dump($newProperty);

            $action = "error";

            echo('--------------');

            dd($table_data);

        }

    }

    if($action == "ok"){

        $newProperty->save();

        foreach ($request->file('more_img_path') as $imagefile) {

            $image = new Image;

            $path2 = $imagefile->store('images/resource/property/gallery/', ['disk' =>   'my_files']);

            $image->p_id = $property_id;

            $image->img = "public/".$path2;

            $image->save();

        }



            // **********************activity log************************

            $newLog = new Log();

            $uname;

            $user;

            foreach(session('login_user') as $id => $details){

                $uname = $details['name'];
```

I'm mention below error screenshot. There showing error "newProperty(save);" code line.
Can someone help me to fix this error? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIwmz.png)

Comment: please check your database. make sure you declare primary key and autoincrement.

Comment: You should have already an entry with p_id is equal to 5. Or it casts l_id to int and you have it on your table. It's hard to say.

Comment: I have already declared primary key as auto increment. But still same problem

Comment: Check the `properties` table. From the error you have shared, it seems like the value you are storing for the primary key column is already present in some other row of your `properties` table.

Comment: yes. I checked now. There was stored property id 5 instead of id number 1. after i edited that table manually. like I removed id number 5 and changed it to id number 1. But strange thing is after fix that, next data i stored as id number 5. And that data also passed to database successfully. But those stored data showing only database, not display in webpage. So, after i added next data as id number 6. that one showing in database and webpage.